# How can I know What Error is happening to my jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I've been using JasperSoft iReport for generating reports from java program. I noticed that when I create a report using ireport, and some error happens, there is no clue, that I can find out what is actually going on ? There is a window Report Problem Window, but this window is always blank. I just cannot find out any error and report is not compiling.

Comment: Did you try viewing the error in Report Output Window ?

Comment: Report Output window is always blank

Comment: Try posting your jrxml file.